# How to check empty node using FreeMarker

Tags: xml, freemarker

I can't find the right build-in function to check if a node is empty.
Here is the `xml` sample node -

```
<address>
    <street1/>
    <street2/>
    <city/>
    <zip/>
    <country>BD</country>
</address>
```

I have tried using `adr.street1?has_content` but this does not returns `false` since the node is present.

```
<#list address as adr>
    <#if adr.street1?exists && adr.street1?has_content>
        street1 is present //this line executes but it shouldn't be since street1 has no value.
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adr.street1` is a sequence that contains a single node, so it "has content". Furthermore any subvariable query (`.` or `[...]`) just gives a sequence of matching nodes, never the node itself. (So for example, if you have only one `street1`, `arr.street1[0]` just gives back the original sequence. Which can be quite surprising, but it's just the approach of XPath.)

So, do this check: `adr.street1?children?has_content`. Because the number of children is 0. If `street1` can only contain text, then this is nicer: `adr.street1 != ''`.

You do not need existence checks, like `!` or `?exists`, because XML queries are guaranteed to return some result. If there's no match, it's just an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning non-empty for some reason. You should be able to get away with using size or length for this.

```
<#list address as adr>
    <#if adr.street1?exists && (adr.street1!?size > 0 || adr.street1!?length > 0)>
        street1 is present
    </#if>
</#list>
```